# Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: chromium. Please verify its path and try again

Tags: centos, yum

> Following error occurred when I'm trying to update using "yum" command.
>   There's no any Internet connection issue. I just tried to get access to get solution from Error message given Red-Hat Article. but
>   that Red-Hat knowledge-base support for active subscribers only.

```
[cloudera@quickstart /]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.9 kB     00:00     
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: mirror2.totbb.net
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
http://install.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/yum/itecs/public/chromium/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: chromium. Please verify its path and try again
[cloudera@quickstart /]$
```

Answer (score 5):

> I managed to solve this issue by doing this .

---

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cd /
[cloudera@quickstart /]$ cd etc/yum.repos.d
[cloudera@quickstart yum.repos.d]$ sudo vi chromium.repo
```

> Edit the "enabled=1" line in bellow text chunk in chromium.repo file
>   as "enabled=0"

---

```
[chromium]
name=chromium for RHEL Linux $releasever - $basearch - Base
baseurl=http://install.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/yum/itecs/public/chromium/$releasever/
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-chromiumpublic file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-chromiumpublic1 file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-chromiumpublic2

[chromium-source]
name=chromium for RHEL Linux $releasever - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://install.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/yum/itecs/public/chromium/$releasever/SRPMS
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-chromiumpublic file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-chromiumpublic1 file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-chromiumpublic2
gpgcheck=1
```

---

> Then tried the "sudo yum update all" command as following. it's now
>   worked for me

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ 
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo yum update all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.9 kB     00:00     
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: mirror2.totbb.net
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
chromium-el6                                                                                                                                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
chromium-el6/primary_db                                                                                                                                                       |  17 kB     00:00     
cloudera-cdh5                                                                                                                                                                 |  951 B     00:00     
cloudera-cdh5/primary                                                                                                                                                         |  43 kB     00:00     
cloudera-cdh5                                                                                                                                                                                146/146
cloudera-gplextras5                                                                                                                                                           |  951 B     00:00     
cloudera-gplextras5/primary                                                                                                                                                   | 2.4 kB     00:00     
cloudera-gplextras5                                                                                                                                                                              9/9
cloudera-kafka                                                                                                                                                                |  951 B     00:00     
cloudera-manager                                                                                                                                                              |  951 B     00:00     
cloudera-manager/primary                                                                                                                                                      | 4.3 kB     00:00     
cloudera-manager                                                                                                                                                                                 7/7
epel                                                                                                                                                                          | 4.3 kB     00:00     
http://mirror2.totbb.net/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
Trying other mirror.
epel                                                                                                                                                                          | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                                                               | 5.9 MB     00:22     
extras                                                                                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                                                             |  29 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                                                            | 4.2 MB     00:02     
webtatic                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.6 kB     00:00     
webtatic/primary_db                                                                                                                                                           | 208 kB     00:00     
No Match for argument: all
No package all available.
No Packages marked for Update
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```